# Making an SBCL program stop

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

I used to have a function in GNU clisp like this:

```
(defun showVersion()
    (let ((currentVersion 1.0))
        (format t "My software current version: ~a.~%" currentVersion))
) ; End of showVersion.
```

and call it using this code:

```
 ;;(when (string= (car *args*) "--version")
(when (string= (cadr *posix-argv*) "--version")
    (showVersion)
    (bye))
```

It would make the program stop after it has been called.

But this doesn't seem to make the program stop with SBCL.

What is the way to get the same result ?

Comment: replace `(bye)`to`(quit)`

Comment: TLDR; `(uiop:quit)` (with an optional result code)

Comment: I tried both solutions but for (uiop:quit) I get some error message:
"Package UIOP does not exist." I presume it is because I need to install something.

Comment: Yeah, you need a `(require :uiop)` or the like first to load the package.